# How to re-enable disabled form fields after submitting form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm able to disable blank form fields, on submission, with:

```
<form method="GET" onsubmit="onsubmit1(this)">
...
<script type="text/javascript">
function onsubmit1(thiz) {
    $(thiz).find(':input').each(
        function() {
            if (!$(this).val()) {
                $(this).attr('disabled', true)
            }
        }
    )
}
```

The problem is that the fields remain disabled, when the user selects to export a .CSV file, as the page doesn't refresh after the .CSV file is downloaded to the browser.

I would like the disabled input fields to be re-enabled, when the user selects to export a file.

Bonus points for solving this via the form's `onsubmit` handler, and not via the submit button's `onclick` handler as there are many submit buttons.

Comment: hmmm so what you need is once the download has completed you want the inputs to be re-enabled?

Comment: Unless you disable the default submit processing, the page will be reloaded when you submit it, and everything will be re-enabled.

Comment: Yes, I would like the blank fields to be re-enabled. I updated my question to make that clear.

Comment: The page does not reload, as the response from the server is to push a .CSV file to the browser, and not HTML content.

Comment: What's the reason for setting blank fields to disabled? Is it just that you don't get those (empty/null) values at the server side?

Comment: When the form *does* post, I want the URL to have only non-blank fields in it.

Comment: after you get response from download function enable them.Paste more code to clarify

Comment: I don't know how, hence my question.

Answer (score 0):

I have made demo please refer this Demo

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dubeynee/CH3CU)

```
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="submit" value="Enabled" id="btn2">
<input type="submit" value="Disabled" id="btn1">  

$('#btn1').on("click", function () {
            alert($(this).val());
            $('input:text').attr('disabled', true);
        });

        $('#btn2').on("click", function () {
            alert($(this).val());
            $('input:text').attr('disabled', false);
        });
```